# How to set disabled mat-input to enabled when I click on it?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

I have a `mat-input` and in default it is disabled to change text. How to set disabled to enabled when I click on it? And after that I want to change to disabled again when it lose the focus or I hit enter.
Can I do that?

Comment: What's a matinput? mat-input? "How to set to disabled to enabled when clicking on it" do you mean how to be able to toggle disable/enable?

Comment: Yes, it is mat-input. And I want to set enabled to change the text when I clicked to the input.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create a state variable, and assign it to input disabled attribute on `click` then on `mouseout` events

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" (click)="disabled=false" (mouseout)="disabled=true">
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi"
          [attr.disabled]="disabled?'':null">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: Another way to set the disabled flag is to use the `readOnly` tag on a mat-input. Angular Material api documentation: [https://material.angular.io/components/input/api](https://material.angular.io/components/input/api)

Comment: is it cleaner? better? I feel like this was maybe the intended use by the material team, over `[attr.disabled]="disabled?'':null"`, which, btw, works well for me, but I'm switching to `readOnly`.

Comment: @JasonEvans as per : https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/issues/44#issuecomment-268987174 `attr.disabled` is (in my view) superior to `readOnly` as unless you are in a case where you simply want to use the graphical aspect of an input but update it's value, you would want to prevent exactly that when disabling a field.

Comment: doesn't work with reactive forms.

Answer (score 23):

I used this way, in my opion is better way

```
<input matInput placeholder="Email" [ngModel]="franchise.user_email" formControlName="email" readonly>
```

Comment: Readonly working but [disabled]="true" why this not working ?

Comment: @SHUBHASIS disabled does not work on `input` since it should be set on FormControl inside your component in case of Reactive forms. `name: ({ value: '', disabled: this.isEditMode })`

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a FormGroup, then you should not disable the form in the HTML Template. It will not work if you try to disable in HTML together with FormControl. Instead, it should be done within the FormGroup. Try this:

```js
  template: `
    <mat-form-field [formGroup]="form">
      <input matInput placeholder='Name' [formControlName]="formControlName">
    </mat-form-field>
  `
```

and:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        name: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: this.disabled })
    });
}
```

Also...not a big deal but..you should really be doing:

```
public form: FormGroup;
```

instead of:

```js
public form: any;
```

Don't forget the import as well

```js
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
```

Btw, the name inside of the form group declaration should match whatever you have set in the HTML.
So:

```xml
<input formControlName="myInputName">
```

and

```js
this.form = this.fb.group({
    myInputName....
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me...

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
     <textarea matInput cdkTextareaAutosize placeholder="Event Description" matTooltip="double-click to enable editing"
     [(ngModel)]="textareaSample" name='desc' readonly [readOnly]="readonly" (dblclick)="toggleEdit()"  ></textarea>
```

and in the component...

```
 textareaSample = "Tack Spanish Main hulk deadlights man-of-war transom Jake a caulk belay.";
 readonly: boolean;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.readonly = true;
  }
  toggleEdit(): void {
    this.readonly = !this.readonly;
  }
```

and the CSS...

```
textarea { font-size: 1.2em; padding:0px;}

textarea[readonly]{ background-color: transparent;}
textarea { background-color: #eee;}

textarea[readonly]:hover {  cursor: pointer;  cursor: default; background-color: transparent }
textarea:hover { cursor: auto; background-color: #eee;}
```

This example is using Angular Material controls. Just double click on the input to enable editing. The same principles should work with other controls too, like PrimeNG and similar.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use semantically incorrect attributes like using **readonly** for **disable**. Reactive form has a property disabled, you can use it with matInput.

```
 foodCtrl: FormControl;
 disabled: boolean = true;
 ngOnInit() {
   this.foodCtrl = new FormControl({value: '', disabled: this.disabled})
 }
```

Here I used Reactive form with disable property, it will change with the change of disabled property.

Live Example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-input-disable)

Answer (score 1):

This is the better way to disable the input field...

```
<input matInput formControlName="description" readonly />
```

in input add `readonly`  only.

its work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
<input 
  matInput 
  placeholder="Email" 
  [ngModel]="data.userEmail" 
  formControlName="email" 
  readonly
/>
```

use only `readonly`

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and use the [editing tools](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) so it's more readable.